# Poisson Distribution Function infinite loop

Tags: r

I have the following code that is trying to simulate the deposition of metallic atoms onto a cold substrate; however, it runs in an infinite loop.

Can anyone see where I'm making a mistake?

```
l <- 20
n <- 2000
e <- 1000
lsize <- matrix(0,l,l)
deposits <- rep(0,n)
avg.deposits <- rep(0,n)
prob <- rep(0,n)
n.deposits <- rep(0,n)
for(m in 1:e){
  for(j in 1:l){
    for(k in 1:l){
      lsize[j,k] <- 0
    }
  }
  for(i in 1:n){
    ra <- runif(1)
    x <- floor(1+l*ra)
    ra <- runif(1)
    y <- floor(1+l*ra)
    lsize[x,y] <- lsize[x,y]+1
    s <- 0
    for(j in 1:l){
      for(k in 1:l){
        if(lsize[j,k] <- 1){
          s <- s+1
        }
      }
    }
    n.deposits[i] <- n.deposits[i]+s
  }
}
for(i in 1:n){
  avg.deposits[i] <- n.deposits[i]/e
  prob[i] <- avg.deposits[i]/(l*l)
  deposits[i] <- i
}
plot(deposits, prob)
```

Comment: `lsize` is a vector, but you are calling `lsize(x,y)` like it's a function. It's very unclear what this function is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Try to understand first how vectors work in R. You probably meant lsize[x, y], use `[` not `(` and try some R basics tutorial on vectors to understand how it works.

Comment: I edited the vectors to use brackets instead of parenthesis, it removed the function error I had been receiving.  Now, I receive the following error. `Error in lsize[j, k] <- 0 : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`

Comment: try `lsize <- matrix(0,l,l)` instead of `lsize <- rep(0,l)`.  Also, you can zero the matrix via `lsize[] <- 0` instead of using the for loop ...

Comment: I changed lsize to a matrix which rid the program of the subscript error; however, it now runs in an infinite loop.

Comment: How do you know that it is infinite? It looks terribly inefficient, so I expect it is just slow. Print out the loop counters to see what it is doing, then rewrite in C or C++ if you can't face the contortions of vectorizing your code. Rcpp makes this pretty easy.

Comment: I'm very new to R and coding in general, which explains why it is inefficient code.  How do I print out loop counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no infinite loop problem.

This is easy to check if you go ahead and run your code with smaller `l`,`n`,`e` arguments. Your code scales sub-optimally (super-linearly in this case) when increasing any of the arguments mentioned.

Obvious points:

1. Preallocate matrices. Do not allocate `lsize` in each loops again and again.
2. Limit your functions calls; to `runif()` in this case. You do not have to call the same function thousands of times. Call it once outside the loop to generate the random number you want and then within the loop just access the next element in line.
3. Use `print` and `cat` statement to print out the loop counters you use. Try small values that ensure what they program does what you want and then set your counters to thousands.
4. Look to vectorize your code when possible. Eg. If 'a  = runif(100)' and you want to set all the instances where `a < 0.5` to equal `4` there is no reason to loop over all elements of `a` sequentially. `a[ a < 0.5] = 4` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your well explained suggestions!

Comment: I am glad I could help.